# Not enough space between front mounted child bike seat and rider

Tags: child-seat

I ride a city bike. We recently switched from using a trailer to a front bike seat for transporting our son:

[image]

Unfortunately, the back of the child seat (Yepp Mini) does not leave much space for me to mount/unmount comfortably. We also considered the bobike seat, but I think I'll face the same problem.

Is there a way I can use a front bike seat without buying a new bike? I am not so tall, so there are not many bikes that suit me.

We live in the Netherlands.

Comment: I actually ended up finding a nice solution. I am posting this question because I was really at a loss and the solution I found doesn't seem to be well known. I will let others answer first though.

Comment: There's generally not a lot of room out there for a load.  Some seats sit in front of the bars, like a basket and are frankly terrifying.  The seats that go over a rear rack tend to upset the balance of the bike easily.  My personal preference is for the seats that sit over the top tube and don't rotate with the bars.  Downside is they force your knees apart while riding which can range from slightly annoying to incredibly irritating.  There are no great answers.

Comment: @Criggie I posted an answer with the solution that worked for me

Comment: great work - please click the tick/check box on the left side of the answer to mark it as "accepted" so SE knows the question has a validated answer.  Thank you for the closure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something called a "mother steering" ("moederstuur" in Dutch). We replaced the steering bar of our bike with this, and viola, ~20cms of extra space between me and the mounting point of the bike seat!

[image]

[image]

Disclaimer: the steering we bought is heavier than the original steering, it took a couple of days to get used to it

There seem to be a few different such products, serving a similar function, at least available in the Netherlands.